# Windows 10 Required files taking up over 100gb of space

Tags: windows

I have had windows 10 on a partition for a while, but I am very new to using it. I noticed today that I was missing a lot of space on that partition. When I opened the Storage settings to try and figure out where all of the space as allocated I noticed that the Windows system files were taking up a huge chunk of space.

Is this correct for a Windows 10 installation for a single user? I can't figure out how to get this space back and none of the answers I get from googling solve the problem and most are over a year old.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions with how to trouble shoot this!

[image: Reserved space 127gb]

Comment: no it should not be so much but are you dual booting and had you done a clean install or upgraded any old windows(7/8.1) to windows 10 ??

Comment: I am both dual booting and this was an upgrade to Windows 10. That upgrade was a few years ago, and I haven't used the windows partition much. Only just noticed the size.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a utility such as
[TreeSize Free](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/)
to locate where this space is used.

There is a good chance that it is used by the file `Windows.edb`, which is the
database file of the Windows Search service.
This is a hidden file located in the following folder:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Windows.edb
```

My own recommendation is to
[Disable Search Indexing in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/93666-enable-disable-search-indexing-windows.html)
and install instead [Voidtools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/).
Disabling Windows Search is done in
*Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off*
and uncheck "Windows Search". You may then delete `Windows.edb`.

Otherwise, if you decide to keep Windows Search, to regenerate `Windows.edb`
do the following:

- Stop the Windows Search service in the `Services.msc` applet
- Delete `Windows.edb`
- Restart the Windows Search service
- Open *Control Panel > Indexing Options > Advanced* and click
  "Delete and rebuild index".

(The last step may be enough.)

Comment: I'm assuming disabling search indexing would also disable Win10's native file search via Cortana?  _(Not intended to advocate one way or the other, just an important FYI if it does)_

Comment: @JW0914: You are probably right, as I'm not using Microsoft's lame Start menu. There are third-party solutions that are better than Microsoft's, such as [Open-Shell-Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu).

Comment: I'm not sure in what Win10 bi-annual update they merged it, but Windows Search was merged into Cortana and removed from the Start Menu _(I could never get used to the >=Win8 start menu either and have always used Stardock's Start8 and Start10)_.  If using large taskbar buttons, search appears as an actual text box within the Task Bar, whereas if using small buttons, it shows as the standard search icon (magnifying glass).  Since it merged with Cortana, it's almost as fast as Ubuntu's file manager's search functionality

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Looking at the tree size made me realize another thing. Is it possible that Windows is seeing my linux(ext4) partition and adding that to the system files. Since it can't read the partition in the explorer.

Comment: BTW the edb file is only 3gb so that isn't the problem

Comment: Windows only reports on its partition. Have you seen anything using TreeSize?

Answer (score 0):

That is 4 times the amount that i have and ive had it installed for quite some time. I am using version 1809. If I remember correctly in version 1903 and ongoing they introduced a feature that reserves a certain % of your hard drive so that windows updates can always have room to install. I would also check how much of what data is in there for cache and old windows updates and maybe even windows upgrade files by using disk cleanup and seeing the breakdown there.

Comment: Just an FYI, the bulk of size from Windows upgrade/setup files is the highly compressed `install.wim` / `install.esd` file, which is normally not larger than 7 - 8GB.  Once a bi-annual update concludes, the largest data size is the leftover `C:\Windows.old` directory _(which enables a restore the previous version of Windows)_

Answer (score 0):

It is very unusual, might be if you upgraded any old version of windows or somehow because of dual booting(assumption).
But you can try the following if it helps:

Open Settings

> Update & Security
>
> Recovery
>
> Reset this PC
>
> Choose an option
>
> Keep my files(I recommend to still backup all your data of all your drives{if you are dual booting})

If this did not work, I suggest doing a clean install using the official Microsoft ISO from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).